# D portion of PID calculation

Tags: c, pid-controller

I am implementing PID control for motor speed control. In the specification I have been told to implement filtering technique using the following equation for D part. I am done with Implementing the PI control and it works perfectly fine for me.

[image]

Now what I understood so far is that s represents `"dx/dt"` generally which corresponds to the rate of change of error but here i can relate it with rate of change of feedback. `Td/N` is for limiting the all over gain output(hope i got this right). Now to represent this in terms of C code I tried with the following way.

```
s = (CurrentFeedback()-Old_Feedback)*100/(MaxFeedback()); //to calculate the % change in feedback
    s = s*1000/sampleTime;      //1000 is multiplied because sampleTime is in milliseconds
    D = (Td*s)/(1+(s*Td/N));
    D = D*KP;   //Kp is multiplied as per the standard pid equation.

    Old_Feedback = CurrentFeedback();
    PID = P+I-D;
```

Well the results by adding D is not what I have predicted. I just want to know that ..did I implement the D portion equation correctly? Am I making in mistake in the understanding the basic maths of differentiation?

NOTE: I am not in liberty to change the recalculate the kp,ti,td as it comes directly from the VFD. Thanks a lot in advance. Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Shouldn't percent change be `(current-old)/old`? Why do you have `max` in the denominator?

Comment: well i put max because max possible change in feedback is the mx feedback it self....

Comment: I would suspect integer division.  How big is `N` compared to `s*Td`?  If it is bigger, your lower term is rounded to 1.  and if `N` is smaller than `Td`, the whole formula is truncated to 0.

Comment: N is usually 5 but in the system there is a limit it wont go beyond 10

Comment: my doubt is in the realization of the equation. I am not good in maths :D

Comment: What are the types of your variables? Is `N` an `int`?

Comment: my final D Term is S32, N is U8, Feedback is S32, diff time is U32 as well

Comment: @AShelly.. I suspected the same...i took sample at different change in feedback and recalculated everything...at no point it;s being rounded 0. I took care of the 2 point decimal precision but proper multiplication and division...but i havent added here so that people dont get confused by seeing all that stuff

Comment: I'm confused by not seeing "that stuff". You say the types are integral, but then you say you have 2 decimal point precision.   GIve at  least one concrete example of inputs, expected outputs , and actual output.

Comment: @AShelly I suspect the integer values are scaled x100 to get the 2 decimal points of precision ? Scaling like that is often used for integer calculation, e.g. in control loops.

Comment: You are right @Morten Jensen

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the sample time is high enough and the sensibility of the measure is high the D will only add noise, because any small change will be inmediately attacked by the D control, creating an awful ripple at the end.
In most systems you don't need a D if you can live with a slower control. If you still want to use a D then be sure that it's far smaller than P and I.

And maybe you can change your last symbol.

Comment: Mostly D will remain the off only..but if user activates it system should be capable enough to deal with it